# expression for people entering a place, moving, noise

Tags: phrase-requests

I need an expression for the ambiance of when people are **entering** an event venue such as a hall, stadium, etc., and what to call it when **this action stops**.

Comment: *bustle* or *hustle and bustle*

Comment: *[milling](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/mill-around) [around](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/mill-around)* or *[about](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mill+about)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Hubbub](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hubbub) is the noise made by a large crowd, and the hubbub is usually said to *die down*.

Comment: Good answer. I was going to say this too. I don't know of anything else closer than Hubbub.